# how to call internal function after chrome.storage.sync.get callback in chrome extension+reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I have chrome extension with reactjs.

My component has some internal functions and I called them after callback of chrome.storage.sync.get.

But I got "**XXX is not function**" error.

Here is my code snippet.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  func1(){}
  func2() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(data) {
      this.func1();
      this.setState(...);
    })
  }

}
```

I can't call func1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retain the context of your app inside of your callback.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  func1(){}
  func2() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, (data) => {
      this.func1();
      this.setState(...);
    })
  }
}
```

Note that I changed your callback to an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which does not bind its own `this` value and instead uses the same context as the function it was called from - in this case, your app.